# Updating Duplicate Rows then deleting all except one

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

I am using SQL Server 2005 to try to find all the duplicates of a certain item and change the quantity so that it will equal the number of duplicate items.  Then I plan to remove all the duplicate rows except one.

Here Is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Quantity = COUNT(Item)
WHERE COUNT(Item) > 1

SELECT * FROM Item
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is your table structure? Does your table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want.

```
with toupdate as (
     select item, count(*) as cnt
     from t
     group by item
    )
update t
    set quantity = cnt
    from toupdate
    where t.item = toupdate.item
```

The CTE calculates the value for each item.  The update clause then does the update.